# How to block China and keep it blocking after reboot? Having problems in implementation

Tags: centos, networking, iptables

I am trying to use [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/931153/999577).

I am running Centos 7 and iptables v1.4.21.

**Why I need it?**
I have several Wordpress blogs. I get every day from 4000 to 20000 bruteforce logins, nonexistent files, and automatic attempts to find vulnerable plugins and files to later exploit. And they are all from China. Other countries also, but less than 1000 a day. So I want to help a little the security and block those requests before they reach the webserver or PHP engine to save hardware resources. I considered asking the question on Security StackExchange, but I thought here is better. No idea though. I want to avoid duplicate questions.

My script looks like this:

```
# Create the ipset list
ipset -N china hash:net

# remove any old list that might exist from previous runs of this script
rm cn.zone

# Pull the latest IP set for China
wget -P . http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone

# Add each IP address from the downloaded list into the ipset 'china'
for i in $(cat /etc/cn.zone ); do ipset -A china $i; done

# Restore iptables
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

And the rules file looks like this (there are no spaces, no new lines):

```
[root@myserver etc]# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
-A INPUT -p tcp -m set --match-set china src -j DROP
[root@myserver etc]#
```

And when I run the script I get such errors:

```
ipset v7.1: Element cannot be added to the set: it's already added
ipset v7.1: Element cannot be added to the set: it's already added
ipset v7.1: Element cannot be added to the set: it's already added
ipset v7.1: Element cannot be added to the set: it's already added
(a plenty of the same lines)
```

Here I see two or three problems:

- When I added the IP's to IPset once, they are already there. Isn't it better to add something at the beginning of the script that removes all the IPs from the China blacklist?
- If yes, how to do that?
- also how to restore the ipset after reboot? Maybe just making the same script run on boot?

P.s. after adding that I see this - which seems to be good, but still I'd like to fix the above mentioned problems:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             match-set china src

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: IMHO if you are tying to defend against a professional attacker, IP-based blocking will not really help as it can be circumvented. Did you consider asking the question on [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It's not as much as defending. I have several Wordpress blogs. I get every day from 4000 to 20000 bruteforce logins, nonexistent files, and automatic attempts to find vulnerable plugins and files to later exploit. And they are all from China. Other countries also, but less than 1000 a day. So I want to help a little the security and block those requests before they reach the webserver or PHP engine to save hardware resources. I considered asking the question on Security SE, but I thought here is better. No idea though. I want to avoid duplicate questions.

Comment: I understand. In that case, of course, your approach seems reasonable (but unfortunately I can't help you with the problem you describe).

Comment: Thanks, let's hope someone will help

Comment: You may want to add the explanation you gave me into the question though; I could imagine that other contributors would also think immediately about professional hacking activities and recommend a strategy unsuitable for your problem setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipset` has a subcommand to atomically swap two sets: `swap` (or `-W`). This allows to populate a new set, swap it with the older set, and remove the now useless set with the new name. That's better than flushing the set (with `ipset flush china`) because this would temporarily leave the system exposed, and allows to replace a set with different parameters without having to remove the *iptables* rules referencing it (because a set can't be destroyed while still referenced). I'm also switching to *ipset*'s newer syntax, which is the only one kept in recent [manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/ipset/ipset.8) (both syntax work).

```
# -exist for idempotence: don't trigger an error the 2nd time this script is run
ipset -exist create china hash:net

# old cn.zone will stay around if download fails
wget -O /etc/cn.zone.tmp http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/cn.zone && \
    mv /etc/cn.zone.tmp /etc/cn.zone

ipset create china.tmp hash:net
sed 's/^/add china.tmp /' /etc/cn.zone | ipset -exist restore   
ipset swap china china.tmp # new set atomically replaces older set
ipset destroy china.tmp

/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Replacing the loop with (properly formatted input fed to) `ipset -exist restore` improved the loading of entries by two orders of magnitude (here loop test went from ~ 6s to ~ 0.06s). `-exist` is here in case the input list itself contains duplicates, to ignore them and prevent a premature abortion when loading entries. If you think the input list might have unparsable content, then either filter it to render it parsable (eg: remove any empty line) or revert to a loop, but rather than `for` better use a `while read` construct like:

```
while read net; do
    ipset -exist add china.tmp "$net"
done < /etc/cn.zone
```

`iptables-restore` can be left in the current script or could be put in a separate script (which would depend on this current script since iptables' rules depend on the set having been already created) to keep the functionalities of updating the set and updating iptables' rules separate.

I'm sure the script can be further improved (especially around loading the `cn.zone` file which is expected to fail at boot time even if this won't affect the overall result. Maybe this too should be split).

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be working. Do you think you can help to make it run at boot time? And also in editing the script in order to add a different country to the list so that it will block 2 countries? If you think you can help I can ask a new question.

Comment: to use more than one zone, simply do multiple wget and add those multiple zone files to `sed`'s args. This script can be run at boot time (considering it should be run before network, it's thus normal wget will fail and that's why it now won't delete the previous zone file). About boot time *integration* sorry you'll have to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. Multiple wget it's clear. What's the right args syntax for sed, let's say if we have the additional files `turkey.tmp` and` /etc/tk.zone`? I went thrugh the manual, but I am not comfortable with regex, etc.

Comment: Remade my comment. If you want to use one set per country (rather than one global set) you need to do everything for each country, probably factorized in a loop. If you just want to add everything in the same set, just add all .zone files as parameter to sed (sed takes all further arguments as extra files to work on). Sorry but it's now more about putting an idea as an algorithm and implementing a program (even if it's a shell code) rather than having an issue with the available tools.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
# IPSET BLOCKZONE (select country to block and ip/range) ###
# http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/
ipset=/usr/sbin/ipset
iptables=/usr/sbin/iptables
zone=/path_to_folder/zones
if [ ! -d $zone ]; then mkdir -p $zone; fi

$ipset flush blockzone
$ipset -N -! blockzone hash:net maxelem 1000000
for ip in $(cat $zone/{cn,ru}.zone /path_to/blackip.txt); do
    $ipset -A blockzone $ip
done
$iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m set --match-set blockzone src -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix 'Blockzone'
$iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m set --match-set blockzone src -j DROP
$iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set blockzone dst -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix 'Blockzone'
$iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set blockzone dst -j DROP
$iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set blockzone dst -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix 'Blockzone'
$iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set blockzone dst -j DROP
```

source: [blackip](https://github.com/maravento/blackip#ipset-squid-rules)